# Duda sobre significado codigo sscanf==3

Tags: c, string

Hola muy buenas un amigo me ha pasado un codigo de un ejercicio que debemos hacer y no entiendo la parte del codigo en la que pone

> while(n==3);

Me he dado cuenta que si cambio el valor ese no me da todos los datos que me deberia dar . Aqui les dejo el codigo y el texto con el que tenemos que trabajar (la idea es coger separados tanto las entradas "E" de la gente como las salidas "S")

```
void main(){
int n;
char linea1[100],jornada[100],nombre[100],apellido[100],marcaje[100],par[100],impar[100];
FILE *fichero;
fichero=abrirFichero();
fscanf(fichero,"%[^\n]",linea1);
do{
    fscanf(fichero,"%[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\n]",jornada,nombre,apellido,marcaje);
    do{
        n=sscanf(marcaje,"%s %s %[^\n]",par,impar,marcaje);
        printf("%s",par);

    }
    while(n==3);
}
while(!feof(fichero));


}
JORNADA NOMBRE  APELLIDOS   MARCAJES
08:00   Julia   Gonzalez    8:45E 14:50S
06:00   Antonio Lopez Herrera   8:00E 14:45S 16:00E 17:00S
07:36   Maria   Perez Alonso    8:00E 14:45E 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Andrés  Gomez   8:05E 14:45S 15:30E 17:00S
08:00   Sara    Martinez Conde  8:00E 14:45S 15:30E 16:45S 18:00E 20:00S
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) de `sscanf`, en caso de lectura exitosa, el valor de retorno indica los argumentos que fueron llenados correctamente. En este caso los argumentos a llenar son: `par`, `impar`, `porcentaje`; en total 3.

De ahí que `while(n == 3)`, repite la iteración mientras sigan habiendo lecturas exitosas.